# How to ignore Duplicates while selecting data in a sql Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two rows in a table which are having same values in two columns.

How can i select only one row of them.

```
Id       IP Address      Page       Datetime              Country   Region  
1506    64.233.172.146  /index.php  2017-05-12 15:02:57   India Telangana
1507    64.233.172.146  /about.php  2017-05-12 15:02:59   India Telangana
1508    64.233.172.146  /index.php  2017-05-12 15:03:01   India Telangana
1506    64.233.172.146  /contact.php2017-05-12 15:05:04   India Telangana
```

I want my output as

```
Id       IP Address      Page       Datetime              Country   Region  
1506    64.233.172.146  /index.php  2017-05-12 15:02:57   India Telangana
1507    64.233.172.146  /about.php  2017-05-12 15:02:59   India Telangana
1506    64.233.172.146  /contact.php2017-05-12 15:05:04   India Telangana
```

Comment: Use Min(Id) and a Group by the rest of the columns

Comment: Can you please explain little better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and an inner join for this:

```
select *
from your_table t1
join (
    select ip_address, page, min(id) as id
    from your_table
    group by ip_address, page
) t2 using (ip_address, page);
```